# installing laravel/spark failed [Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout]

Tags: git, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I cloned private laravel project from GitHub using GitHub Desktop, the project contains spark library.

I have spark account the team working on. I connected the Github with it and joined the repo

[image]

Then I executed the `composer install` command on the project's root but I got the following error when trying to install spark

```
- Installing laravel/spark (v4.0.13): Downloading (failed)    
Failed to download laravel/spark from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/laravel/spark/zipball/972a0d0231d75f108b13363af95b848054d521a7" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing laravel/spark (v4.0.13): Cloning 972a0d0231


  [RuntimeException]
  Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout "https://***:***@github.com/laravel/spark.git" 
"C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\laravel\spark" && cd /D "C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\laravel\spark" && git remote add composer "
  https://***:***@github.com/laravel/spark.git" && git fetch composer

  Cloning into 'C:\xampp\htdocs\myproject\vendor\laravel\spark'...
  remote: Repository not found.
  fatal: repository 'https://***:***@github.com/laravel/spark.git/' not found
```

the composer.json includes the spark as described in [the documentation](https://spark.laravel.com/docs/5.0)

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.1",
        "algolia/algoliasearch-client-php": "^1.20",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.2",
        "chumper/zipper": "1.0.x",
        "laravel/cashier": "~7.0",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/spark": "~4.0",
        ...
}

"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://spark-satis.laravel.com"
        }
    ]
```

My OS is windows 10

Node version 9.11.1

npm version 5.6.0

laravel installer 2.0.1